# How to get command value in .conf file

Tags: linux, shell-script, dns, dhcp

I have two linux machines (lubuntu to be specific), one is working as a router and second is working as a client. Router has two ethernet port, first one is connected to internet and second one in connected to client machine. Client has only one ethernet connected to route as shown [image]

Router task is to forward the packets from one ethernet port to another ethernet port and give dynamic IPs and dns to client. I successfully forwarded the network packets and created dhcp server for second ethernet port of router (which is connected to client) but unable to provide dns address dynamically. My dhcpd.conf has following lines for dhcp server

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.200;
  option domain-name-servers 103.61.253.90; #-> static dns ip address
  option domain-name "www.tendawifi.com"; #-> static dns domain name
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.255;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

I want the static dns address to be coming from ethernet connected to internet. I got a command which can provide dns address and dns domain name but how to get it in dhcpd.conf file.

```
resolvectl | grep "DNS Servers" | sed 's/\s\s*/\t/g' | cut -f 4
resolvectl | grep "DNS Domain" | sed 's/\s\s*/\t/g' | cut -f 4
```

Comment: I do not understand why do you need dynamic DNS address. Even if you router's internet address is not static, the interface where you provide accessibility to the client should be static. How do you define a default gateway, if router's internal address is not static?

Comment: @nobody actually router can get internet access from various vendors and hence will get different DNS address.